# CentOS Live CD won't install server

Tags: centos

it's my first time trying CentOS and I'm installing from Live-CD. I want to get a server up and running in VirtualBox but during installation no option for server or desktop comes up.

From step by step guides I've seen online it should be the last option but my installation skips it entirely. Do I need a different ISO, or is there something else I'm not doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the live-CD, you want the DVDs, then you will have the choice of installing the servers.

If you check any mirror (e.g. [this](http://centos.pop.com.br/6.3/isos/x86_64/)), you can see `CentOS-6.3-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso` which is what you want.

Comment: Okay thank you. I seen the download mirrors already, I downloaded the live-CD as I didn't have enough time to download the DVD's, they're quite big.

Comment: I didn't download the DVD but used the minimal install iso instead. It worked but had to install a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the distinction between server and desktop installation is a "MS Window-ism". You select the packages that you need to perform given tasks. If you want a web server, you would install apache, a DNS server would require BIND. If you want the installation to behave like a "Desktop", install the Gnome or KDE package group

Comment: I don't see how it's an MS Window-ism, but I agree on the whole selecting packages to turn the OS into what you want to do. My problem is it defaults to desktop, with gnome and all the like bloating up the system with no choice for a clean server install. For ubuntu there's set iso's for server and desktop. Does centOs have something similar like that? Does server install option not come with live-CD?

Comment: @boundless08 as Renan stated. Your best bet is to use the full DVD

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you follow the loading carefully, at the grub menu, you can select the text-mode install only which I think is the server version of CentOS. At the end of the system/OS install, it will ask you for options to what Daemons/Services you want to install. I might be wrong, but you can give it a go.